# Twitter Bot targeting accounts in specific area

Tags: twitter, bots

I've created a bot with Python to reply when users tweet about a determined subject.

Is there a way to direct the replies to people in a specific area/coordinates?

Thank you in advance x

Comment: This would be in pretty clear contravention of Twitter's guidelines and get blocked for spam rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot Tweet to users in a specific area.

Also, you should read the [Twitter automation rules](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation).

> The reply and mention functions are intended to make communication between Twitter users easier. Automating these actions to reach many users on an unsolicited basis is an abuse of the feature, and is not permitted. For example, sending automated replies to Tweets based on keyword searches alone is not permitted. Spammy or duplicative use of mentions and replies may result in enforcement action, such as the removal of your Tweets from Search or the suspension of your app or account.